# captcha.module error

Tags: 7, theming, debugging

I've just installed recaptcha module and it works fine but I get this error only at the sign up screen (registration screen).

Does anyone know what can I do to fix it??

The error:

Notice: Undefined index: form_id in _captcha_get_posted_captcha_info() (line 604 of /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/captcha/captcha.module).
Notice: Undefined index: captcha_info in _captcha_get_posted_captcha_info() (line 607 of /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/captcha/captcha.module).

Screenshot:

https://image.ibb.co/eYQdhn/Captcha.jpg

Answer (score 1):

check if you have installed the latest module(7.x-2.2) and selected the reCaptchas challenge type dropdowns(for the required pages).. I too had error in displaying reCaptchas..Later i figured that i installed old versions.

Comment: Yes it is: Version: 7.x-2.2

Comment: And yes I selected reCaptchas challenge type